# How to limit DiskCache plugin to a specific storage size?

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I am using the DiskCache plugin. Looking at the documentation, I see the AutoClean attribute says

> If true, items from the cache folder will be automatically 'garbage collected' if the cache size limits are exceeded. Defaults to false.

Where are the cache size limits defined?  I keep running out of my 10 gb of space on Azure websites. How can I limit to 8GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the `subfolders` setting to restrict the number of files that are permitted. It's a stretchy limit based on the number of active files (I/O churn is very bad). The default limit is 400 * subfolders, the maximum is 1000 * subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a rough relationship between the number of subfolders and Gigabytes? e.g. 100 subfolders = 4Gb ?

Comment: That entirely depends on your average output image size. ImageResizer only tracks image count, not the individual or aggregate file sizes, as that's cost prohibitive from an NTFS performance standpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with it.